# linq where AND with multiple OR's

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a DataTable that I'm trying to find distinct rows that differ on a set of columns using LINQ. The DataTable has the following column structure: name, department, shift, empType, onCall. I'm trying to find out all rows that have the same name and department, but where shift, empType or onCall could differ. I've tried the following LINQ but it just gives me the duplicates that are present.

```
from DataRowView e in empDataTable
group e by new
{
  Name = e.Row["name"],
  Dept = e.Row["department"],
  Shift = e.Row["shift"],
  EmployeeType = e.Row["empType"],
  OnCall = e.Row["onCall"]
}
into g
where (g.Count() > 1)
select g;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exclude the columns that you want to allow to be different from the `GROUP BY` key, otherwise LINQ would create a separate group for each combination, so the count would remain `1` for rows other than full duplicates (i.e. rows with all five columns matching):

```
from DataRowView e in empDataTable
group e by new
{
  Name = e.Row["name"],
  Dept = e.Row["department"]
}
into g
where (g.GroupBy(g => new {
        Shift = e.Row["shift"],
        EmployeeType = e.Row["empType"],
        OnCall = e.Row["onCall"]
    }).Count() > 1)
select g;
```

The inner `GROUP BY` groups by the remaining three columns. If all three columns are the same for a `{name, department}` pair, the group is ignored. Otherwise, the group is reported as a query result.

Comment: That gives me all records that have the same name and dept. It's ok if all the columns are identical, I'm only worried about if one of those other 3 columns are different...

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Is there a way I could get the entire row that is different returned?

Comment: @innov83r Yes, the top-level `GroupBy` gives you an `IEnumerable` that has all the rows in the group with differences.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to linq... how do I access that?

Comment: @innov83r Make a `var results = from DataRowView e in empDataTable ...`, then do `foreach (var group in results) {foreach (item in group) { /*Do something with the item*/ } /* ready for next group */}`.